# What is the best approach to declare Api constants

Tags: java, spring-mvc, restful-url

I am developing a RESTful application using Spring Boot. Currently I am using interfaces to declare endpoints because I want to re-use those endpoint in :

1. Spring controllers (e.g. Api.Product.GET_ONE)
2. Integration Testing (e.g. Api.Product.BASE_PATH + Api.Product.GET_ONE)
3. Share same interface in client application

   ```
   public interface Api {
       String CONTEXT_PATH = "/gateway";

       interface Product {
           String BASE_PATH = "/product";
           String GET_ONE = "/{id}";
       }

       interface Order {
           String BASE_PATH = "/order";
           String GET_ONE = "/{id}";
       }
   }
   ```

According to Joshua Bloch, The constant interface pattern is a poor use of interfaces. SonarQube also shows this ([squid:S1214](https://sbforge.org/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1214)) warning.

What is the best way to declare endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't frankly understand your approach,
You could simply do the following which can help you Reuse Endpoints,

```
public interface MyEndPoints {

    public static final String CONTEXT_PATH = "/gateway";
    public static final String BASE_PATH_PRODUCT = "/product";
    public static final String BASE_PATH_ORDER = "/order";
    public static final String GET_ONE = "/{id}";

}
```

1. Spring controllers (e.g. MyEndPoints.GET_ONE)
2. Integration Testing (e.g. MyEndPoints.BASE_PATH_PRODUCT + MyEndPoints.GET_ONE)
3. Share it with client

I think when you don't need it at Client you can have it as Final class at Server. Avoiding complications of `String BASE_PATH` referencing different strings would help in many ways.